# How Can I Expand The Possibilities Generated by Itertools Library?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I built this code to complete a mathematical challenge were I must find a combination that give me the target result.

I must replace "?" for "+", "-", "/" or "*" and add "( )" where it needs to give us the answers.

```
6 ? 6 ? 6 ? 6 = 5
6 ? 6 ? 6 ? 6 = 6
6 ? 6 ? 6 ? 6 = 8
6 ? 6 ? 6 ? 6 = 30
6 ? 6 ? 6 ? 6 = 24
6 ? 6 ? 6 ? 6 = 48
6 ? 6 ? 6 ? 6 = 66
6 ? 6 ? 6 ? 6 = 180
```

But the code below couldn't find the answer for 30, that should be :

```
(6-(6/6))*6 = 30
```

Here's the code

```
import itertools  # Import itertools module for combinations
import datetime  # Import datetime module for timing

# Function to evaluate mathematical expression
def evaluate_expression(expression):
    try:
        return eval(expression)  # Use eval to compute the expression's value
    except:
        return None

# Function to resolve using combinatorics
def solve_with_combinatorics(target_results, factor):
    operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']  # List of mathematical operators
    numbers = [factor, factor, factor, factor]  # List of input numbers
    found_solutions = []  # List to store found solutions
    all_possibilities = []  # List to store all expression possibilities

    # Iterate over target results
    for target_result in target_results:
        found = False  # Flag to track if solution is found
        attempts = 0  # Counter for attempts
        expression_possibilities = []  # List to store expression possibilities

        # Iterate over operator combinations
        for operator_combination in itertools.product(operators, repeat=3):
            attempts += 1  # Increment attempts counter
            expression = str(numbers[0])  # Initialize expression with first number
            for i in range(3):
                expression = f"({expression} {operator_combination[i]} {numbers[i+1]})"
            result = evaluate_expression(expression)  # Evaluate the expression
            
            if result == target_result:  # Check if the result matches the target
                found_solutions.append((expression, result, attempts))  # Store solution
                found = True
                break
            expression_possibilities.append(expression)  # Store expression possibility

        all_possibilities.append((target_result, expression_possibilities))  # Store possibilities

        if not found:
            for possibility in expression_possibilities:
                if evaluate_expression(possibility) == target_result:  # Check if possibility matches target
                    found_solutions.append((possibility, target_result, attempts))  # Store solution
                    found = True
                    break
        
        if not found:
            found_solutions.append(("No solution found", None, attempts))  # Store no solution
    
    # Print and return results
    for solution, result, attempts in found_solutions:
        if result is not None:
            print(f"Expression: {solution} = {int(result)}")  # Print solution expression and result
        else:
            print("Expression:", solution)  # Print no solution message
        print("Attempts:", attempts)  # Print number of attempts
    
    return all_possibilities

# Target results and factor
target_results = [5, 6, 8, 30, 24, 48, 66, 180]
factor = 6

print("\n[ACHIEVE EQUALITY FOR THE MATHEMATICAL EXPRESSIONS BELOW]")
for i, result in enumerate(target_results):
    print(f"{factor} ? {factor} ? {factor} ? {factor} = {result}")  # Print target expressions
print()

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print(f'## Program started at: {start_time}\n')  # Print start time
all_possibilities = solve_with_combinatorics(target_results, factor)  # Call the solver function
end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
total_time = end_time - start_time
print(f'## Program ended at: {end_time}')  # Print end time
print(f'## Total time: {total_time}\n')  # Print total execution time
print("\n[All possible combinations and combination results]")

largest_target_result = max(target_results)
for target_result, possibilities in all_possibilities:
    if target_result <= largest_target_result:
        print(f"\nTarget Result {target_result}:")  # Print target result label
        for possibility in possibilities:
            print(possibility)  # Print each expression possibility
        print()
```

Here is part of output:

```
## Program started at: 2023-08-26 14:30:45.595289

Expression: (((6 * 6) - 6) / 6) = 5
Attempts: 40
Expression: (((6 - 6) * 6) + 6) = 6
Attempts: 25
Expression: (((6 + 6) / 6) + 6) = 8
Attempts: 13
Expression: No solution found
Attempts: 64
Expression: (((6 + 6) + 6) + 6) = 24
Attempts: 1
Expression: (((6 * 6) + 6) + 6) = 48
Attempts: 33
Expression: (((6 + 6) * 6) - 6) = 66
Attempts: 10
Expression: (((6 * 6) - 6) * 6) = 180
Attempts: 39
## Program ended at: 2023-08-26 14:30:45.604267
## Total time: 0:00:00.008978
```

So, the question is: How to increase the possibilities of combinations beyond the 64 possibilities?

I tried to plot all the possibilities in screen to see if there were something wrong in the code, but no. I believe that it's a limitation of intertool library.

Comment: "I believe that it's a limitation of intertool library." - everything in the library works perfectly as it should. The limitation is in your code: you never introduced the possibility to "add "( )" where it needs".

Comment: Thierry, if you see the results posted below there are "( )" being used, but is follows a pattern.

Comment: I saw, and this shows that you are always doing the calculations in the same order: first operator, then second, then third. You have to try all 6 possible orders.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, any idea how to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to increase 64 possibilities, we should create the possible parentheses groups of the numbers.

Here is an algorithm that finds the possible parentheses groups.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def product(*iterables):
    if not iterables:
        yield []
        return
    for i in iterables[0]:
        for p in product(*iterables[1:]):
            yield [i, *p]


def find_numbers(s):
    return list(map(int, "".join(map(lambda i: i if i.isnumeric() else " ", s)).split()))


def find_chars(s):
    return list(filter(lambda i: not i.isnumeric(), s))


def unique_append(result, item):
    if item not in result:
        result.append(item)


def bracket_combinations(numbers):
    def side_brackets(result, select, left, mid, right):
        unique_append(result, [left, mid, *right] if select == left else [*left, mid, right])
        for bracket in brackets(select):
            if select == left:
                unique_append(result, [bracket, mid, *right])
                unique_append(result, [*bracket, mid, *right])
            else:
                unique_append(result, [*left, mid, bracket])
                unique_append(result, [*left, mid, *bracket])

    def brackets(n):
        step = 2
        result = [n]
        while step < len(n):
            for i in range(len(n) - 1):
                left = n[:i]
                mid = n[i: i + step]
                right = n[i + step:]
                unique_append(result, [*left, mid, *right])
                if len(left) >= 2:
                    side_brackets(result, left, left, mid, right)
                if len(right) >= 2:
                    side_brackets(result, right, left, mid, right)
                for bracket in brackets(mid):
                    unique_append(result, [*left, bracket, *right])
            step += 1
        return result
    return brackets(numbers)


def insert_operators(group, chars):
    expr = ""
    for i in range(len(group)):
        if isinstance(group[i], list):
            expr += "(" + insert_operators(group[i], chars) + ")"
            try:
                if expr[-1] != group[i + 1]:
                    expr += next(chars)
            except IndexError:
                pass
        else:
            expr += str(group[i])
            if i != len(group) - 1:
                try:
                    expr += next(chars)
                except StopIteration:
                    pass
    return expr


def get_products(ops, numbers):
    products = []
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if i == len(numbers) - 1:
            products += [[numbers[i]]]
        else:
            products += [[numbers[i]]] + [ops]
    return products


def find_expression(ops, numbers, target):
    for p in product(*get_products(ops, numbers)):
        stmt = "".join(map(str, p))
        chars = find_chars(stmt)
        for bracket_comb in bracket_combinations(find_numbers(stmt)):
            expr = insert_operators(bracket_comb, iter(chars))
            try:
                res = eval(expr)
                if res == target:
                    return expr, res
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                pass


def main():
    ops = "+-*/"
    numbers = [6] * 4
    targets = [5, 6, 8, 30, 24, 48, 66, 180]
    for target in targets:
        expr = find_expression(ops, numbers, target)
        print(expr)


main()
```

Output:

```py
('(6*6-6)/6', 5.0)
('6+(6-6)/6', 6.0)
('6+(6+6)/6', 8.0)
('(6-6/6)*6', 30.0)
('6+6+6+6', 24)
('6+6+6*6', 48)
('(6+6)*6-6', 66)
('(6*6-6)*6', 180)
```